# Apache Camel Routes on Pivotal Cloud Foundry

Tags: apache-camel, cloud-foundry

We have few scheduled jobs implemented via apache camel routes & qaurtz scheduler. We are migrating our application to pivotal cloud foundry. Does Pivotal cloud foundry support apache camel routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not? They run in a java container.  See my example running in spring boot with a cloud foundry manifest: https://github.com/amaline/camel-example.git

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Foundry (CF) supports deployment of applications through so called build packs for different technologies. For example, if your application is running on JVM, you need to deploy it to CF with corresponding Java Build Pack. 
One common way to deploy Camel routes to CF is to package Camel routes as Spring Boot Java apps and then deploy them to CF using Java build pack.